# How to extract a subset from a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe that contains several columns including a column called A (containing integers).

I would only like to consider the rows of table that correspond to $A \ge 3$.

What would be the syntax for this?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways

```
df[df['A']>=3]
```

Maybe using query

```
df.query('A >=3')
```

Or using the .loc

```py
df.loc[df['A'] >= 3]
```

This question is posted on several places.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should consider using the `.loc` method of a dataframe. It allows to select rows using a logical expression.

Have a look at [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) link.

In your case something like `df.loc[df.A>=3]` should do the work. Selecting columns is also an option.